# React - File Uploader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fine-uploader

So I have been using this https://github.com/FineUploader/react-fine-uploader. Is there a way  to add `cursor: pointer` to FileInput element's style.

What I tried is:

```
     <FileInput
        uploader={this.uploader}
        className={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
        style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
      >
        <span>{this.props.children}</span>
      </FileInput>
```

then it generated:

```
<input type="file" class="react-fine-uploader-file-input" style="bottom: 0px; height: 100%; left: 0px; margin: 0px; opacity: 0; padding: 0px; position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%;">
```

without the `cursor: pointer` property

Comment: not the answer you are looking for but just to correct your code, `className` is used for literally names of `classes` that you want to assign, you are putting css into it which is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement using CSS. You need to create one css and need to provide on file input `className="file-upload"`.

See this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-file-uploader) demo.

**CSS**

```
.file-upload input[type='file'],::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**FileInput Component**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

import FileInput from 'react-fine-uploader/file-input'
import FineUploaderTraditional from 'fine-uploader-wrappers'

const uploader = new FineUploaderTraditional({
  options: {
    request: {
      endpoint: 'my/upload/endpoint'
    }
  }
})

const fileInput = (
  <FileInput multiple accept='image/*' uploader={uploader} className="file-upload">
    <span class="fa fa-upload file-label">Choose Files</span>
  </FileInput>
)

render(fileInput,document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass style for your span element.
Use proper class name and do not pass the styles directly into the className.

```
     <FileInput uploader={this.uploader} >
        <span style={{cursor : 'pointer'}}>{this.props.children}</span>
     </FileInput>
```